# Having text "spill out" of the div boundary

Tags: html, css

I am making myself sort of a library to help me make registrations forms faster. The format that I have been using is some form field on left (in 50% wide div cell), with help text on the right (in 50% wide div cell) if I have any help text. This is done one "form line" at a time, so I cannot put two form fields into done div cell to make things line up nicely. Image for visual aid: https://imgur.com/a/aKp50VF

I am trying to figure out, how can I have the help text on the right "spill over" to the next "form line" if its longer, so I can keep everything nicely formatted.

```
<div id='form_container'>

    <div id='left_form_container'>
        Form field here as needed       
    </div>

    <div id='right_form_container'> 
        Help text if any
    </div>

</div>
```

The CSS looks like this

```
#form_container {
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-top:10px;
    }

#left_form_container {
    width:48%;
    float:left;
    padding-right:15px;
    overflow:hidden;
    }

#right_form_container {
    width:48%;
    float:left;
    padding-left:15px;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your visual aid is kind of unclear as it looks exactly like you want it to show? If you just want there to be more room for content on the right, why not just have a single container that's not formatted into rows?

Comment: I want the help text to be right next to the form field it relates to. Lets say that I have "first name" and "last name" fields above the school name. if I just make left and right containers (with no row formatting), the help text related so "school name' will be next to the "first name" field.

Comment: You could create a [CSS Grid template] (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) then ensure your help text and input field share the same row. Or use [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to break a single container into multiple Divs and accompany with help text containers that are left blank if no help is available. I think this is a bit broad, there are tons of ways this can be done. Specify any limitations?

Comment: Oh, that is awesome. Took me some time to wrap my head around it, but it does what I need and then some. I need to start keeping up with "new" stuff more often. Many thanks.

Comment: Glad that helps, converted to an answer, feel free to suggest anything you'd want clarification or examples on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a [CSS Grid template](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) then ensure your help text and input field share the same row. Or use [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to break a single container into multiple Divs and accompany with help text containers that are left blank if no help is available.